# Specifying default parameters Silverlight RIA service class

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

Everyone,

How can I specify default parameters in a Silverlight context class? Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public partial class MyContext : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyConnectionString>
{
    //other functionality omitted for simplicity

    public IQueryable<Foo> GetFoo(int id, string optional = "")
    {
        //foo stuff
        return this.ObjectContext.Foo.Where( p => p.id = id);
    }

}
```

i have the db tables imported to the edmx file
now in the generated MyContext.g.cs file, the default parameter is not being treated as default.
instead this is what is being generated:

```
public EntityQuery<Foo> GetFooQuery(int id, string optional)
{
    //stuff omitted
}
```

And I cannot call the above method with a single parameter like so GetFooQuery(1). It gives me a compile time error stating there is no such method that accepts a single parameter.

So is this how it works? How can I specify default parameters in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this signature (one integer parameter).

Because WCF RIA Services (domain service) compile fine on the server-side code, but the generated code that makes it over to the client side contains the parameters as **non-optional**, as such all of the client code that wants to use the default for the optional parameter fails to compile.